# CSV Dictionary, comparing 2 CSV files and replacing values based on matching values

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I am trying to compare between 2 CSV files and if one of the columns' values match, then I
will need to replace the values of the other csv file with the second csv file's values.

Example:

`Book1.csv`:

```
Alfa,Beta,Charlie,Delta,Echo,Foxtrot,Golf,Hotel,India,Juliett,Kilo
A1,B1,C1,D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,
A2,B2,C2,D2,E2,F2,G2,H2,I2,J2,1
A3,B3,C3,D3,E3,F3,G3,H3,I3,J3,
A4,B4,C4,D4,E4,F4,G4,H4,I4,J4,
A5,B5,C5,D5,E1,F5,G5,H5,I5,J5,1
A6,B6,C6,D6,E6,F6,G6,H6,I6,J6,1
A7,B7,C7,D7,E7,F7,G7,H7,I7,J7,
A8,B8,C8,D8,E8,F8,G8,H8,I8,J8,1
A9,B9,C9,D9,E9,F9,G9,H9,I9,J9,
```

`Book2.csv`:

```
Oscar,Papa,Lima
A1_x,B1,K2
A2,B2,X2
A3_x,B3,L2
A4_x,B4,K2
A5,B5,J2
A6,B6,A2
A7_x,B7,AS
A8,B8,S3
A9_x,B9,S1
```

If `Book2.csv` column "Oscar"'s values are equal to `Book1.csv` "Alfa"'s values (`A2==A2`, `A3!=A3`, `A4==A4`), then `Book2.csv`'s "Lima" values will overwrite whatever is in `Book1.csv`'s "Beta" values.

So the output for `Beta_New` will look like this (it looks like this because of the code below where I am switching and calling the columns by a dictionary:

`xtest_file.csv`:

```
Beta_New,Echo_New,Foxtrot_New_ALL,Hotel_New,India_New,Charlie_New
X2,E2,F2,H2,I2,C2
J2,E5,F5,H5,I5,C5
A2,E6,F6,H6,I6,C6
S3,E8,F8,H8,I8,C8
```

My code so far:

```
import csv

fieldnames_dict = {
    'Beta': 'Beta_New',
    'Echo': 'Echo_New',
    'Foxtrot': 'Foxtrot_New_ALL',
    'Hotel': 'Hotel_New',
    'India': 'India_New',
    'Charlie': 'Charlie_New'
}

1_open_cd_csv = open("book1.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')
1_reader_cd_csv = csv.DictReader(1_open_cd_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
1_header_csv = next(1_reader_cd_csv)

2_open_cd_csv = open("book2.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')
2_reader_cd_csv = csv.DictReader(2_open_cd_csv, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
2_header_csv = next(2_reader_cd_csv)

open_output_test_csv = open(xtest_file.csv, "w", encoding="utf-8", errors='ignore')
writer_output_test_csv = csv.DictWriter(open_output_test_csv, delimiter=',',
                                        quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL,
                                        fieldnames=list(fieldnames_dict.values()))
writer_output_test_csv.writeheader()

for row_in in 1_reader_cd_csv:
    if row_in['Kilo'] == "1":
        row_out = {new: row_in[old] for old, new in fieldnames_dict.items()}
        writer.writerow(row_out)
        #if 2_reader_cd_csv[Oscar]'s values = 1_reader_cd_csv[Alfa]'s values:
            #then the output for "Beta_New" = the values for 2_reader_cd_csv[Lima]
```

or mabye something like this:

```
for row_in in 1_reader_cd_csv:
    alfa_match = 2_reader_cd_csv['Oscar'] matches with = row_in['Alfa']
    if alfa_match != none and row_in['Kilo'] == "1":
        row_out = {new: row_in[old] for old, new in fieldnames_dict.items()}
        #then the output for "Beta_New" = the values for 2_reader_cd_csv[Lima]
        writer.writerow(row_out)
```

Comment: What is wrong with the output you're getting now?

Comment: Its just not running =(, also im missing an append from book2 to book1

Comment: Well, one obvious thing is that variable names can't start with a digit, like `1_open_cd_csv` , `2_header_csv`, etc. You should be getting a `SyntaxError: invalid decimal literal` for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Break your code into smaller chunks for each part:

1. Read rows of "book1.csv" where Kilo="1" to `file1`
2. Read rows of "book2.csv" to `file2`
3. Replace values of "Beta" in `file1` based on `file2` values of Oscar
4. Write back to a new csv file

```
with open("book1.csv", "r") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    file1 = [row for row in reader if row["Kilo"]=='1']

with open("book2.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
    file2 = [row for row in reader]

output = list()
oscars = [row["Oscar"] for row in file2]
for row in file1:
    if row["Alfa"] in oscars:
        row["Beta"] = [r["Lima"] for r in file2 if r["Oscar"]==row["Alfa"]][0]
    output.append({new:row[old] for old,new in fieldnames_dict.items()})

with open("output.csv", "w", newline="") as outfile:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile,fieldnames=list(fieldnames_dict.values()))
    writer.writeheader()
    for row in output:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

###### output.csv:

```
Beta_New,Echo_New,Foxtrot_New_ALL,Hotel_New,India_New,Charlie_New
X2,E2,F2,H2,I2,C2
J2,E1,F5,H5,I5,C5
A2,E6,F6,H6,I6,C6
S3,E8,F8,H8,I8,C8
```

Comment: ended up getting an : TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str for   oscars = [row["Oscar"] for row in file2]

Comment: This doesn't give me any errors with the sample files you provided. `row` is a dict, not list. Check for typos in your code.

Answer (score 0):

> If Book2.csv column "Oscar"'s values are equal to Book1.csv "Alfa"'s
> values (A2==A2, A3!=A3, A4==A4), then Book2.csv's "Lima" values will
> overwrite whatever is in Book1.csv's "Beta" values.

You might want to give `pandas` a try:

```
import pandas as pd

#read csvs as dataframes
df1 = pd.read_csv("book1.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("book2.csv")

#replace 'Beta' in first df with the value in 'Lima' where 'Alfa' matches 'Oscar'. 
df1['Beta'].where(df1['Alfa'] != df2['Oscar'], df2['Lima'], inplace=True)
#store as csv
df1.to_csv('new_file.csv')
```

Output df1:

|  | Alfa | Beta | Charlie | Delta | Echo | Foxtrot | Golf | Hotel | India | Juliett | Kilo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | A1 | B1 | C1 | D1 | E1 | F1 | G1 | H1 | I1 | J1 | nan |
| 1 | A2 | X2 | C2 | D2 | E2 | F2 | G2 | H2 | I2 | J2 | 1 |
| 2 | A3 | B3 | C3 | D3 | E3 | F3 | G3 | H3 | I3 | J3 | nan |
| 3 | A4 | B4 | C4 | D4 | E4 | F4 | G4 | H4 | I4 | J4 | nan |
| 4 | A5 | J2 | C5 | D5 | E1 | F5 | G5 | H5 | I5 | J5 | 1 |
| 5 | A6 | A2 | C6 | D6 | E6 | F6 | G6 | H6 | I6 | J6 | 1 |
| 6 | A7 | B7 | C7 | D7 | E7 | F7 | G7 | H7 | I7 | J7 | nan |
| 7 | A8 | S3 | C8 | D8 | E8 | F8 | G8 | H8 | I8 | J8 | 1 |
| 8 | A9 | B9 | C9 | D9 | E9 | F9 | G9 | H9 | I9 | J9 | nan |